# How to add not in query in my LOV from one LOV output

Tags: oracle-apex

I am having a task where I need to add not in query to other LOV from First LOV.

I have 2 LOV items

```
LOV 1 ->  student_ID  -> Select distinct studid from employee;
```

And I set the property of LOV 1 to Multiple and separator as : `,`. This allows me to select multi values from LOV 1 and now whatever i select from LOV 1 need to pass as not in LOV 2

Means second LOV should not contain the values selected in LOV 1

LOV 2 : select distinct stud_id from employee where stud_id not in (:student_id);

How to achieve it ?

This i tried but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that a bind variable always represent a single value. I suggest you read up on bind variables since that is a core concept in pl/sql programming and database development.

To solve the problem you're facing, you can use the `APEX_STRING` api. It has a method to convert a string to a table of `VARCHAR2` with a delimiter of your choice.

```
select distinct stud_id 
  from employee 
  where stud_id not in 
    (SELECT column_value 
       FROM table(apex_string.split(:student_id,',')));
```